# Python Fit Polynomial to 3d Data

Tags: python, scipy, data-fitting

Have a set of data points (x,y,z), and trying to fit a generic quadratic to them using scipy optimize.curve_fit.

I have tried a couple different methods, but can't seem to make it work. Any guidance on why I would be getting this error, or a recommended different method?

Error is "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (12,)"

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize

XY = [(11, 70), (11, 75), (11, 80), (11, 85), (12, 70), (12, 75), (12, 80), (12, 85), (13, 70), (13, 75), (13, 80), (13, 85)]

Z = [203.84, 208, 218.4, 235.872, 228.30080000000004, 232.96000000000004, 244.60800000000006, 264.1766400000001, 254.8, 260, 273, 294.84000000000003]

guess = (1,1,1,1,1,1)

def fit(X, a, b, c, d, f, g):
    return a + (b*X[0])+(c*X[1])+(d*X[0]**2)+(f*X[1]**2)+(g*X[0]*X[1])

params, cov = optimize.curve_fit(fit, XY, Z, guess)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) you need `XY` to be size `(k,M)` where `k` is the dimension and `M` is the number of samples. In your case you've defined `XY` to be size `(M,k)`.

Try the following

```
import numpy as np

...

params, cov = optimize.curve_fit(fit, np.transpose(XY), Z, guess)
```